# Nested Navigators in React Native causes View Controller error in iOS

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator, tabnavigator, react-native-tabnavigator

Our configuration:

- in App.ts, a navigation controller, nesting a bottom tab navigator
- on each tab, the Screen navigates to a stack navigator (so that's five stack navigators, one on each tab)
- on the third tab, so the third the stack navigator, we navigate to a material top tab navigator.

so:

```
1
<NavigationController>
   <TabController>
     <Screen> to Stack Navigator 1
     <Screen> to Stack Navigator 2
     <Screen> to Stack Navigator 3
     <Screen> to Stack Navigator 4
     <Screen> to Stack Navigator 5
   <TabController>
<NavigationController>

2
<Stack Navigator 3>
    <Screen> to Material Top Tab Navigator> 
<Stack Navigator 3>

3
<Material Top Tab Navigator>
    <Screen 1> to View 1
    <Screen 2> to View 2
<Material Top Tab Navigator>
```

When I start the app in the simulator, the app opens on the first tab. when I select the third tab, the following error occurs:

`Exception while executing UI block: A view can only be associated with at most one view controller at a time! View <RCTView: 0x7fae2a52c7e0; reactTag; 1083; frame=(0 0; 0 0); clipstoBOnds - YES; layer = <CALayer> ... Clear this association before associating this view with <UIViewController: 0x7fae2cb90710>`

When I reload the from the error menu, the first screen associated with the first bottom tab appears again--and now when I selected the third tab again, it functions normally.

This problem only occurs in iOS. In Android, the code executes as expected.

When I comment out the stack navigators in bottom tabs 1-4, and instead simply display a text :

```
1
<NavigationController>
   <TabController>
     <Screen> to Text
     <Screen> to Text
     <Screen> to Stack Navigator 3
     <Screen> to Text
     <Screen> to to Text
   <TabController>
<NavigationController>
```

...then the tab functions normally, without the error.

I am guessing this might be a problem with lazy loading on the tabs. I'm a newbie so need some help here.

Comment: Do you have a repository where I can reproduce this issue?

Comment: @ johnrubythecat my github username is satya164

this might be a bug, so I need a repro for the maintainers of react-native-pager-view to fix it, because I have seen this error but don't have a repro yet.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll check it on monday